# The REST API encountered an error in wordpress?

Tags: rest-api, api

The REST API request failed due to an error.

> Error: [] cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

Comment: That's a problem with the service you're calling. You should ask them to fix it. You can also turn off certificate validation in php-curl as a temporary work-around, but that's not a good idea in general: you should get the API provider to get a new certificate.

Comment: Oh, you mentioned Gutenberg in a past revision: is this your own REST API for a self-hosted WordPress? You should set your server up with a valid SSL certificate, e.g. you can get free certificates from letsencrypt.org. Or I assume you have a self-signed certificate that's been autogenerated on your server? You could add that to the central CA list on your server so that it trusts it. But a real widely-accepted certificate would be better.

Comment: That means if i buy a ssl certificat it would solve the problem

Comment: If this is your own server, yes. But there are other options e.g. free certificates, change whatever REST calls this is to use HTTP not HTTPS, set up whichever client this is to trust the server's self-signed certificate, etc.

Comment: I've just searched for "The REST API request failed due to an error" and it's on the site health dashboard: is this only a problem on the health dashboard, and everything else on the site is working? In which case you can might get away with just leaving this: there's a risk other parts of the site will use the same API mechanism and fail, but if you've tested everything and haven't seen that then it might just be OK.

Comment: I have installed Yoast SEO before 1 month but now also it is not showing on google i think because of this Rest api it is not showing. There might be problem of conflict in plugin

Comment: Possibly, but there's probably a problem with your site's SSL certificate too. If you go to your site using HTTPS in a browser do you get any certificate errors there? If you do, you should fix / replace your SSL certificate anyway even if there are plugin conflcts.

Comment: https://www.eod.com.np/ i have added ssl certificate but still it showing this type of error The REST API is one way WordPress, and other applications, communicate with the server. One example is the block editor screen, which relies on this to display, and save, your posts and pages.

The REST API request failed due to an error.
Error: [] cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received  Why??